# extract xml tag value from file where file name has spaces

Tags: ksh

I have a  file 'EXXARS - Physical Inventory Adjustment Report US PDF_es_ES.xlf'

file data:

```
<header>
     <prop-group name="ora_reconstruction">
        <prop prop-type="TemplateCode">XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_AS</prop>
        <prop prop-type="extractorVersion">10.1.3.4.2_1.5</prop>
     </prop-group>
  </header>
```

I need extract the value between   and 
result:
I need this value in the variable XXPO_PHYS_INV_ADJ_ES_ES.

I have coomand which is not working

```
filename='ES - Physical Inventory Adjustment Report US PDF_es_ES.xlf'
sed -n 's:.*<prop prop-type="TemplateCode">\(.*\)</prop>.*:\1:p' filename > ${LOBCODE}
echo " --> ${LOBCODE}"
```

Please help

Comment: Your sed command works fine. If you want the result in the variable: `LOBCODE=$( sed.... );` The `> ${LOBCODE}` will print into a file with a name whatever the variable `$LOBCODE` has.  The filename at the end of the sed command should be `"$filename"`, otherwise sed is looking for a file named filename (use quotes due to the blanks in the filename)

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: we can we use the xmllint --xpath  instead of sed. If so please let me know the command